# “Hopeful”, “Promising” and “Hope-giving”

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, adjectives

I need an adjective to imply that something is **hope-giving**.
I know two relevant words here, but I have no clue if they can be used interchangeably in this sense! That's why I decided to look for the nuance between the adjectives "hopeful" and "promising".

As you can see, dictionaries cannot help learners to distinguish between these two specific words. Please have a look on the following example and let me know whether there is any considerable nuance between them that I have to know.

**Example:**

> - The commercial future of the company looks very ......... .
>   Nearly all projects are just in the initial phase, but everything is going swimmingly. 
>   **a)** [hopeful](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/hopeful) 
>   **b)** [promising](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/promising)

To me, they both mean the same here.

Comment: I would say there is very little nuance between them. _Promising_ has a definite implication that there is evidence for hope - early stages 'promise' future improvement - so it would be my choice for the sentence you quote, but _hopeful_ would not be inappropriate in any way.

Comment: In the US, *hopeful* is more often used for individuals, whereas *promising* is used to describe inanimate objects.

Comment: I see @Kate Bunting. May I ask you about the adjective "hope-giving"? Is it a common term in English? Can it be an interchangeable alternative for "hopeful" and "promising" in that sense?

Comment: No, _hope-giving_ is not an idiomatic expression in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When talking about someone's (or something's) future prospects, I would use **promising**.

**Promising** means *showing* promise or potential. It is something an entity *displays*. **Hopeful**, on the other hand, more often means *feeling* hope; a company's leadership may be **hopeful** about the company's future.

Of course, as you have discovered, "hopeful" can also be used as a near-synonym to "promising". It is not incorrect to say "The company's future looks very hopeful," meaning the future *inspires* hope. But because the word also (and to my ear, more often) means *feeling* hope, I would not use it this way unless I had a good reason to, such as avoiding repetition.